# django get distinct value from queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class Organisation(User):
    organisation_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    first_parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent', related_name="first", blank=True, null=True)
    second_parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent', related_name="second", blank=True, null=True)



    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

and my Parent model:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.parent_name
```

Here I want the list of parents in my templates that are unique. I dont want repeted parents.

I have gone through:

```
organisations = Organisation.objects.all().distinct('first_parent')
```

but this is not supported by mysql.

I tried to get list of first parents from organisations then its set gives only unique value like:

```
organisations = Organisation.objects.all()
parent_list = organisations.first_parent ## it gives error says 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'first_parent'
```

I have thought about grouping in template but i was not able to..

What I want is list of first_parent or organisation with its id in template so that I can redirect it to some page with id like

```
{% for parent in parent_list %}
    {{parent}}
    <a href="{% url "some_url" parent.id %}"
```

first_parent I get should be unique.

How can I get this. please help

Answer (score 0):

For backend that do not support `distinct('...')` like MySQL, use `Organisation.objects.values('first_parent').distinct()`,
this gives you a list of `{'first_parent': value}` dictionaries

To get a list of just the values do

```
parent_list = [org['first_parent'] for org in Organisation.objects.values('first_parent').distinct()]
```